# Textures not working on glTF Embedded Models. Picture Explains The Issue. (GODOT ENGINE)

Tags: 3d, textures, models, godot, uv-mapping

[image: Model With Texture]

I wanted the tree to look a bit more stylized, or have a bit more to it than just flat planes. Yet when I tried to put this texture on it, it just looks completely wrong. Is this a model issue or a mapping issue?

Comment: I'm changing the color of it later the texture it's self is my issue

Comment: 2 questions (edit them into your question). How did the tree look before? What is the expected result after?

Comment: Well before it had no textures at all, just a blank white model. I want it to look like a pine tree, where the effects would go from the middle to the edges of the leaves. It's probably just a mapping issue but if you could help I would appreciate it

Comment: Have to disappoint you - proper UV mapping is a much more complicated topic than it seems.

Comment: I've been trying to learn, I just don't really know where to go to do that

Comment: other than youtube that is

Comment: eh well I guess this was a mapping issue, back to the Youtube hole I go Xd

Comment: I'd say you need to solve that in Blender, ArmorPaint, or some other texture and uv painting software.

Answer (score -1):

Mapping issue, will fix in the future

Comment: It's fine to answer your own questions on GDSE, however this response has been flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Low quality answers tend to attract down vote &/or get deleted (or worse, down voted first **and** then deleted). A better version of this answer would provide someone else with enough information to solve the same problem on their own. Please consider editing to provide more information about why mapping is the problem &/or how you discovered mapping was the problem source.